# Windows Phone 8.1 : How to add data annotations to enum value types to get the appropriate string

Tags: c#, enums, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Universal App with an enum in it. I use this enum both in my Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 projects.

I have already looked at these links
[Windows Phone 8 - enums & DataAnnotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957640/windows-phone-8-enums-dataannotations) 
But this seems to be for Windows Phone 8 Silverlight

Here is my enum

```
   enum MyEnum
    {
         [Display(Description="Move forward")]
         Forward,
         [Display(Description="Move Backward")]
         Backward
    }
```

The EnumHelper that takes the enum value and returns the description is as follows

```
    public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum enumValue)
        where T : Attribute
    {
        return enumValue
            .GetType()
            .GetTypeInfo()
            .GetDeclaredField(enumValue.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttribute<T>();
    }
```

I call GetAttribute to get the string from my enum. I am using this while displaying data, Instead of displaying the enum as a string, I am displaying the string from the Description Annotation Name.

I am able to write a converter for Windows 8.1 which can take the enum value and give me the description in the annotation Display. However I am unable to achieve the same behavior in Windows Phone 8.1.

In Windows 8.1, the following namespace will help me

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

However since it is not there in Windows Phone 8.1. How do I achieve a similar behavior? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't rely on any special behavior when using the DisplayAttribute class (caused by any other libraries), you can create your own version of it.

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class DisplayAttribute : System.Attribute 
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public DisplayAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Now you shouldn't require the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace.